# Can I travel to France with a valid Schengen visa issued by Sweden?

Tags: schengen-visas

I was issued a 3-month multiple entry Schengen visa to attend conference in Sweden in June 2017. I went to the conference and wow I want to visit France with my family. I know my family members will need Schengen visas, but:

1. Can I visit France with my valid Schengen visa? In the visa, it mentions 'conference' and I've heard that French border officials can be very strict about this.
2. We all might have single itinerary and hotel bookings; will it affect getting their visas or my entry into France?

Comment: Your visa has both a period of validity ("from" and "to" dates) and an allowed "duration of stay."   Does "three months" indicate the period of validity, or the duration of stay?  If it is the period of validity, how many days do you have remaining from your duration of stay, and is it enough days for the trip you are planning?

Comment: Also, can you say something about where _on the visa_ "conference" is mentioned?

Comment: You visa mentions conference? Where? I have attended conferences exclusively in Schengen but my visa never said Conference on it?

Answer (score 1):

You can travel to any country with multi entry visa. If one of two conditions are fulfilled.

- you have already done a trip for which the visa is issued
- you are planing to do the trip later with the same visa

On the border crossing you may be asked for the booking or purpose of traveling. If you fulfill one of the statements above you are free to use you visa for any purpose.

Note, this rules do not apply for single entry visas.